# UI events from ViewModel to View in Android Java

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-livedata

I am trying for an elegant way to send an event from a ViewModel to a View in Android using Java. This would be for one shot events like for showing a toast. [Android recommends to use MutableStateFlow](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/guide/ui-layer/events#handle-viewmodel-events). However a similar pattern does not seem to be available for Java. What would be the recommended way, using LiveData and an observer in the activity? Does someone have a simple code pattern?

Comment: If your event is really `one shot` op, you can simply use a `listener callback` or better, `LiveData`.

Comment: which was your approach ?